# restore ldap from machine backup files

Tags: ldap

I am looking to restore my ldap from a tar archive backup of my machine.
I attempted to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 and it failed.  Thus I backed up all my files and installed 14.04 fresh.

I see this link which is promising:
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200402/msg00560.html

Basically if i put all the files for ldap back and install via `apt-get` will that work?

Answer (score 1):

two directories need to be restored:

```
/var/lib/ldap
/etc/ldap
```

`cp` your backups for both of these folders into the directories.

also make sure to set correct permissions for the openldap user on `/var/lib/ldap/*`

I just completed this and verified it works as a solution.